# Why do the training curve fall sharp suddenly?

Tags: machine-learning, cnn, machine-learning-model, word-embeddings, matlab

I am training a CNN classifier on a binary balanced dataset. The dataset has 4500 numbers of tweet data along with the class of the tweet. During training, I am applying, GLOVE embedding of 300 dimensions, 'adam' solver to run the model for 33 times of epochs. Besides, the sequence length I have considered is 31.

I have applied 200 filters which include a number of convolution2dlayers,batch normalization layers, relu layers, dropout layers and max-pooling layers. The drop out I have considered is 0.2 and the max pool layer is of size [1 sequence length].

The training curve is approaching smoothly until the end period where it has fallen sharply. Here, I have attached the training plot I receive:
[image]

Would you please explain to me why does this sudden fall occur? And how could I get rid of this?

Thanks,

Comment: It's clearly an anomaly, so I would start by investigating it as a technical bug: it is possible that the process was interrupted abruptly during the computation of the last stage, causing for example an incomplete model used for evaluation or an incomplete test set

Comment: @Erwan. Hi. thaks for your comment. I think it's not an anomaly. I have tried to run the model for 10 epochs and it's giving the same sudden sharp fall.